# Excel ADO "The access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time"

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I retrieve data from SQL Server and store it on a sheet in Excel and then I run an ADO UPDATE query within Excel to update data on a different sheet.

I have not come across this error during developing yet users are reporting they see this error frequently:

[image]

Note that the file is located on a network drive, but even after copying the file to a different location, it is still producing said error.

Code:

```
Dim rs  As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
         "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

Set rs = GetOverview
shUpdateSLSheet.UsedRange.clear
WriteHeadersToSheet rs, shUpdateSLSheet.Name, 1
shUpdateSLSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

If (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then GoTo NoData

cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [SL$] INNER JOIN [UpdateSLSheet$] " & _
                    "ON ([SL$].ID = [UpdateSLSheet$].ID) " & _
                        "SET [SL$].[CS_A] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_A]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[CS_B] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_B]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[CS_C] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_C]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[CS_D] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_D]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[CS_E] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_E]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[CS_F] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[CS_F]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[Solved By SR] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[SolvedBySR]" & _
                        ", [SL$].[Comments] = [UpdateSLSheet$].[Comments]"

cmd.Execute

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

As soon as cmd.Execute gets executed the error comes up.

EDIT: I have no clue why this is happening. I'm going for an iterative approach instead of using ADO in this case.

Comment: Just a guess, but are there by chance any functions on the `UpdatedSLSheet`?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an update query on a data linked worksheet? Update the actual back end instead.

Comment: @VictorK There are no functions on UpdateSLSheet, the SL sheet has BeforeDoubleClick and Change events though

Comment: @Comintern users need to see refreshed data. That's what the query does, it updates the data on the user's Excel sheet with the data it just retrieved from SQL Server

Comment: @tutu That could be it possibly - if you are updating an entire worksheet it might set off events that conflict with you query. I suggest trying to disable events. But I agree with Cominterns suggestion - it appears to be an easier way achieving the same thing.

Comment: @VictorK in the code above I am using Application.EnableEvents = False to disable the events temporarily while it runs. I'm not sure what Cominterns means, update the back end, as in the database? This happens without any issues. The problem occurs when I want to refresh the data for the other users in their Excel (front-end). But I've given up on a solution, I am going to rewrite the code and drop ADO.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. Is this a shared workbook?

Comment: @Comintern no, each user has their own copy. If one user changes something, this needs to be reflected in the copy of each user

Comment: So the code above is looping through a directory somewhere that all of the individual users' copies are stored and running the update on all of them? I'm trying to get a handle on how you intended this to work.

Comment: @Comintern so basically, one user updates one or more values, these get send and stored in SQL Server. Whenever other users click refresh, this code runs and downloads data from the database and updates the values on their sheets in their own copy of the workbook. Am I making sense?

Comment: @tutu did you find a solution for this ? If yes, mind posting it ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I never found the solution for this, I rewrote the code to not use ADO. Thanks for posting a solution, will try this if I come across the error again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the open method for the record set and use the lock type
so the data base actual locked when some one is adding and when this person finish adding the data base will save changes and then another person can start adding

Comment: I don't think this necessary because each user is using their own copy of the Excel file. Data retrieved from the database is stored on a sheet in their own copy, and only then the UPDATE query runs and produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I had the same issue and found a solution: I tried using the **OLD** driver in the connection string, and it worked like a charm, even if the workbook is an XLSM !
Hope it helps someone.

```
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & wbName
sConn2 = ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
On Error GoTo hell
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
'con.Open sConn & sConn2
con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
       "DriverId=790;" & _
       "Dbq=" & wbName & ";" & _
       "DefaultDir=" & wbname & ";ReadOnly=False;"
```